# Chess board positions

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

How can i make this so the user types positions in console (table[4,5]) i want that user types that?

```
int[,] table = new int[8, 8];
         for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
                {
                    if ((i + j) % 2 == 0)
                    {
                        table[i, j] = 0;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        table[i, j] = 1;
                    }
                }
            }
           Console.WriteLine("4 - king");
           Console.WriteLine("3 - queen");
           Console.WriteLine("4 - hunter");

           table[4,5] = 2;
           table[6,7] = 3;
           table[2,2] = 4;

           for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
                    {
                        Console.Write(table[i, j] + " ");
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
```

What should i do to make this work?And if i type this it doesnt work:
Thats why i have to put figures in different rows or columns how do i fix this

```
       table[4,5] = 2;
       table[4,7] = 3;
       table[2,2] = 4;
```

Comment: I didn't understand a thing. What are you trying to do? Please take your time to explain your problem, we can't guess it

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"?  We don't know what you're trying to do here, you have to actually explain the problem.

Comment: You overwrite `table[4,5]` in the first loop. Just move `table[4,5] = 2;` to after the first loop? Also, you are testing for equality with `==`. Assignment is `=`.

Comment: sorry my board looks like 01010101 in 8x8 and i want it somewhere to be 01010121 and 01013101 and one more to change the 1    01040101

Comment: @БогданБогојевић: This sounds like a good opportunity for you to step through the code in a debugger while it executes and examine the runtime values and behavior.

Comment: Thank it solwed the problem  @JohnnyMopp

Comment: But i still cant do more than one change

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
                {
                    if ((i + j) % 2 == 0)
                    {
                        table[i, j] = 0;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        table[i, j] = 1;
                    }
                }
            }
            table[4, 5] = 2;
            table[5, 8] = 3;

Comment: I am sorry for not being able to present he problem well i just started learning programming and i am new here so i need little time to blend

Comment: by the way the problem is solved

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_notation_(chess)

Comment: Also, I suggest using an enum for the pieces, not just 2 = king, 1 = queen thing - it's confusing otherwise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing the assignment operator "=" with the logical comparison operator "==". Your second line is just comparing table[4,5] with 2 and probably returning false.

Change it to:

```
table[4,5] = 2;
```

Also, even if you manage to assign a value to table[4,5], you will overwrite it in the next lines. You should move that line to the end of the first nested loop. Just before the second "for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)"

Comment: how can i make so the positions are insert buy user in console

Comment: Do you know how to do that?

Comment: You can use Console.ReadLine() to interact with the user